# RegEx Nearest word match greedy

Tags: c#, regex, greedy

I have this text

```
"(Objectid < 200 OR ObjectID > 600) and (test or best) W/5 AND (apple OR 10a) AND (Objectid < 100 OR ObjectID > 500)"
```

I want to get the string(s) containing the substring `And` or `Or` wrapped in `( )` nearest to `W/digit` (from the left or right) in the above string, where `digit` is a number.

In the above example I should get (test or best) (apple OR 10a)

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(\([^)]*\))\WW/\d+\W(?:AND|OR|IN)\W(\([^)]*\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var items = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
var match = rgx.Match(subjectString);
while (match.Success) {
    items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value));
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```